# Is inset with vertices merging to prevent overlap possible? v2.8

Tags: mesh

I want to apply an even inset but need to prevent overlap which is inevitable for the shapes I'm working with using the inset tool. Is there anyway I can have the vertices/edges auto merge that overlap?

I've ticked the Auto Merge option for the inset tool but that doesn't work for me, perhaps because the overlap is so great.

Comment: Select every vert, hit alt+m then choose by distance and adjust the distance in the pop-up menu in the left bottom corner.

Comment: Too much overlap to do that unforunately, it would merge verts I need to keep. I'm talking about a deep inset.